# jQuery - Tabs - Need a little help/direction

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, tabs

Once again, I have a question about jQuery, but I'm doing my best to learn, but sometimes tutorials don't give me everything I need.

I'm trying to make a set of tabs work, however, nothing seems to be working..

Here's the code I'm working with:

**HTML:**

```
     <!-- TAB SECTION -->
<div id="tab_container">
     <ul id="tab_list">
        <li><a class="how_on" href="#how">How</a></li>
        <li><a class="why" href="#why">Why</a></li>
        <li><a class="what" href="#what">What</a></li>
        <li><a class="who" href="#who">Who</a></li>
        <li><a class="when" href="#when">When</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="images/tab_top.jpg" width="864px" height="6px" alt="" border="0" />
</div>

<!-- HOW -->
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab" id="how">
        <p><strong>HOW IT WORKS:</strong></p>
    </div>

<!-- WHY -->
    <div class="tab" id="why">
        <p><strong>WHY:</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tab_container
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 35px;
    width: 864px;
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul#tab_list
{
    width: 683px;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#tab_list li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.how,
a.how:link,
a.how:visited,
a.how_on
{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 135px;
  height: 29px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

a.how:visited, a.how:link, a.how:hover
{
    background-image: url("../images/how_tab.jpg");
    background-position: 0 -58px;
}

a.how_on
{
    background-image: url("../images/how_tab.jpg");
    background-position: 0 -29px;
}

.tabs
{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f3f9fb;
    width: 836px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 14px 6px 14px;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**jQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 //if this is not the first tab, hide it
 jQuery(".tab:not(:first)").hide();

 //to fix u know who
 jQuery(".tab:first").show();

 //when we click one of the tabs
 jQuery("#tab_list a").click(function(){
 //get the ID of the element we need to show
 stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
 //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
 jQuery('.tab:not(#'+stringref+')').hide();
 //fix
 if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3) == "6.0") {
 jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).show();
 }
 else
 //display our tab fading it in
 jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).fadeIn();
 //stay with me
 return false;
 });

});
```

Just wanted to say thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the jQueryUI tab? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I didn't know about this, it looks pretty cool, is it easy to implement? Have you used this before?

Comment: yes you can call it the defacto tab implementation for developers/designers using jQuery.

Comment: i tried this but you can't get away from the theme it already has for you, which is making it completely useless to me unfortunately.
I'll keep trying to get the above to work or just write my own jquery.. it doesn't make sense though, it should show the first tab, hide the rest, then show on click when the ID# matches.. I don't get why it's not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the codes are not fully implemented so I'll just point out one obvious what I assume is a typo.

```
jQuery(".tab_list a") //now
jQuery("#tab_list a") //should be
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a moron, however that didn't fix the big issue. yet.

Comment: @iamtheratio, yes it doesn't fix the big issue. I was thinking you wanted to 'challenge' yourself to create a tab feature. Now that you realised there's jQueryUI Tab, I seriously suggest you give that a try. You'll be blown away :)

Comment: well I have images and everything already created and ready to go, I just need the tab feature to work correctly. That's what I'm working with now. However, it's not working yet.